# R: Replace character ordinal numbers (first, second, etc.) with just the number (1, 2, etc.)

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I have some strings of addresses with character ordinal numbers (first, second and so on).

> x <- "first bank street"

Output needed

> "1 bank street"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a pure regex task; a regex can't "know" that `first` should become `1`.  You'll have to write some logic to map the values.

Comment: I think you should write a dictionary like `{'first': 1, 'second': 2}`.. Maybe you can find ready.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a helper function to do it for you - although I guess it depends on how high the numbers go. If it's only 1 to 10 then it's easy.

There's no doubt a more elegant way to do this, but this will for sure solve your basic issue.

```
address_string_replace <- function(x) {

  require(tidyverse)

  address_tbl <- tibble(number = 1:10,
                    text = c('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth'))

  address_test <- 1:nrow(address_tbl)  

  tested_value <- tibble()

  for (i in address_test) {

    new_test <- tibble(test = ifelse(str_detect(x,address_tbl$text[i])==TRUE,address_test[i],0))

    tested_value <- bind_rows(tested_value,new_test)

  }

  tested_value <- tested_value %>%
    filter(!test == 0)

  value <- tested_value[['test']]

  address_fix <- address_tbl %>%
    filter(number == value)

  new_x <- gsub(address_fix$text,address_fix$number,x)

  return(new_x)

  }
```

Then you can test it:

```
x1 <- 'first bank street'

address_string_replace(x1) #returns '1 bank street'

x2 <- 'second port avenue'

address_string_replace(x2) #returns '2 port avenue'
```